# Import binary file in R using either typedef struct or numpy

Tags: c, r, numpy

I have a binary file that I am trying to import into R. The data I need to access in the file is unsigned long (though other types are in the file). Using readBin() gets close to what the data should look like, but it deviates from what the data should look like:

```
filepath <- "path/to/file.bin"    
integers <- readBin(con=filepath, what= "int", n=3000, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
```

[Blue is the correct data brought in as a csv, while red is the readBin() input in R.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHSZx.png)

This appears to be an overflow due to unsigned integers, which fortunately can be fixed with the following function, but it only works on some values:

```
int_to_unit <- function (x, adjustment=2^32) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  signs <- sign(x)
  x[signs < 0] <- x[signs < 0] + adjustment
  x
}
```

[Correcting for unsigned integers almost works, but only if the data is negative.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myuox.png)

Basically, the problem is that the 2^32 adjustment only works on data that ends up as negative. If the data happens to overflow > 0, then I cannot recognize it to apply the correction. Worse still, some of it overflows twice, or possibly even more times.

I do have a typedef struct function for C that I could in theory use to import the function, but I have no idea how to do so in R.

```
typedef struct {data definitions I want to use;} dataIwant;
```

I explored using python to solve this problem, but unfortunately it has the exact same problem

```
import numpy as np
xbash = np.fromfile('/binaryfile.bin', dtype='<I')
```

[Numpy runs into the exact same problem that readBin() in R has.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW0Bn.png)

But it is unclear to me how to proceed. My forseeable options are:

1. Write a complicated algorithm to post-process the data,
2. Call out to C to import a unique filetype into R, or
3. Use an intermediary function written in python via the reticulate package

I know this is not a typical problem for the R language - thank you for your time for reading this far.

Comment: I have limited experience with binary formats, but can you not use the `size` argument of `readBin` to specify the correct size?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I left size blank since the default matched how long I knew the data had to be (~2,000 observations). If I manually set size to something larger (like 8), the problem remains but the data is then an incorrect length (~1,000 observations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ralf Stubner had the correct answer, but it was missing one element that could help, but was specific to the binary files I am working with (but general to those hoping to read binary files through C++ into R).

[The problem was that integer values in the file that were too high were wrapping around.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of5YO.png)

The solution was to implement the C++ code that Ralph offered, but critically, to add a line to search for the a starting position in the file that made sense for the data (file.seekg(number);):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector readBinary(std::string fileName, int size) {
    const unsigned long long M = 4294967295LL;
    uint32_t a[size];
    std::ifstream file (fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        file.seekg(513);
        file.read ((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
        file.close();
    }
    NumericVector res(size);
    for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    res(i) = (a[i]) ;
    return res;
}
```

[By adding this line, the data is correctly displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uopFA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I do not find this question that untypical for R, since R has always been a language to interface with code written in other languages like Fortan or C. And while the C API is not exactly easy to use, it is almost trivial to extend R with C++ code using the Rcpp package.  General plan:

- Read the data as unsigned integers of suitable size, e.g. `uint32_t`
- Convert to doubles
- Return as `Rcpp::NumericVector`
- Use `Rcpp::sourceCpp` to make the function available in R

See the [Rcpp attributes vignette](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) for more details.

Edit: Here some example code for the above idea:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void writeBinary(std::string fileName, NumericVector data) {
  int size = data.size();
  int32_t a[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    a[i] = static_cast<uint32_t>(data(i));
  std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  if (file.is_open()) {
    file.write ((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
    file.close();
  }
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector readBinary(std::string fileName, int size) {
  uint32_t a[size];
  std::ifstream file (fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  if (file.is_open()) {
    file.read ((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
    file.close();
  }
  NumericVector res(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    res(i) = a[i];
  return res;
}


/*** R
fileName <- tempfile()
N <- 10
data <- sample(seq_len(2^32 - 1), N)
writeBinary(fileName, data)
all.equal(data, readBinary(fileName, N))
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been working on this all morning - lots to learn on the C++ front. If you have any example code it would be much appreciated. But I think you are right - Rcpp is the way to go to circumvent R's limitations.

Comment: @LeeDrake see the updated answer. Probably not the best C++, but it works and shows how the interface with R might look like ...

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what you are saying now. I can process the binary file in C++ through Rcpp but... the same overflow issue exists (results are identical to numpy & unsigned corrected data in R). I suspect a better solution is in C++, but the odd problem of reversed data continues. I'm increasingly worried that the files produced by the x-ray instruments are fundamentally odd in how they handle large integers.

Comment: As an addendum, the behavior remains the same in R, numpy, and c++, high values overflow to negative values, then continue to positive. Using unsigned definitions only correct overlows that finalized at negative. If they overflowed positive, then they are missed and remain erroneous.

Comment: @LeeDrake Are these numbers greater than 2^32-1? Then they cannot be represented by a 32 bit integer. You will have to analyse the file with a hexeditor to find out what is in there.

Comment: Yes, some values appear to be > 2^32, though most are under that threshold. They might be unsigned long - but if I change "int" in the c++ code with "unsigned long", the behavior persists. 

There may be an alternate solution - I could generate a boolean vector that simply says if wrap around occurred, and then act appropriately. No idea how it is done, but it may be the only way to reconcile the data. 

Sorry to occupy so much of your time with this issue - I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Got it! The answer was to seek the correct file spot, for this particular problem it was file.seekg(513);

Comment: @LeeDrake Good to hear that you found a solution. Care to add it as an answer? That would make the question more useful in the future.

Comment: Just did! Thank you again for your help - I wouldn’t have gotten there if it weren’t for the code you posted.